# DatePicker Not working On Ajax Loaded Content

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have stucked with this problem. The datepicker is working fine on static content.

But fails when content is loaded via Ajax.

I Have tried :-

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $( ".datepickerRange" ).datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            prevText:'',
            nextText:'',
            minDate: 0,
            maxDate: "+1M",
            showOn: "button",
            buttonImage: divadatepicker.image_url+"/calendar.jpeg",
            buttonImageOnly: true
        });
        $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            prevText:'',
            nextText:'',
            showOn: "button",
            buttonImage: divadatepicker.image_url+"/calendar.jpeg",
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: "1960:2015"
        });

            });

$(document).live(function(){
        $( ".datepickerRange" ).datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            prevText:'',
            nextText:'',
            minDate: 0,
            maxDate: "+1M",
            showOn: "button",
            buttonImage: divadatepicker.image_url+"/calendar.jpeg",
            buttonImageOnly: true
        });
        $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            prevText:'',
            nextText:'',
            showOn: "button",
            buttonImage: divadatepicker.image_url+"/calendar.jpeg",
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: "1960:2015"
        });

            });

});
```

It is not showing the even calender small image after content loaded via ajax.

Comment: FYI, `$.live()` is deprecated since 1.7 and was removed in 1.9. use `$.on()` instead http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Call `.datepicker` in your `success` callback function on your ajax call instead of using `.live`, which is deprecated. Example:

```
function initdatepicker(){
    $( ".datepickerRange" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        prevText:'',
        nextText:'',
        minDate: 0,
        maxDate: "+1M",
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: divadatepicker.image_url+"/calendar.jpeg",
        buttonImageOnly: true
    });
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        prevText:'',
        nextText:'',
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: divadatepicker.image_url+"/calendar.jpeg",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: "1960:2015"
    });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    initdatepicker();
});
```

And add this to your `$.ajax` `success`:

```
initdatepicker();
```

Comment: Like this :

success: function(html) {
            // jQuery("#search_result").slideDown("slow");
           // alert(html);
             jQuery("#right_search").html(html);
             jQuery('#TB_overlay').css('display','none'); 
          jQuery("body").css("overflow","auto");
          $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
          },  
Its not working.

Comment: I added an example to my post. Remove `$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker(); ` and use `initdatepicker();` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your help.. But it is still not working. However the function is called on success i test alert  there. But nothing happened :(

Comment: does the content loaded from ajax still have the class `datepicker` or `datepcikerRange`?

Comment: it has following classes :- select_reseve reserve_date datepickerRange field1

Comment: As long as it has the class `datepickerRange`, it should work. Any errors in the console?

Comment: The console helped.. I was using $ instead of jQuery.. You are great. Thanks alot.

Comment: Not sure what other library you have on the page, but you can use `jQuery.noConflict();` (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) to give `$` back to jQuery.

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('input.calendarSelectDate').live('click', function() {
           $(this).datepicker({showOn:'focus'}).focus();
        });
     });
</script>
```