# Datepicker not working in div loaded by ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datepicker

I have a div which is populated by ajax. When done this way the datepicker is not called. I originally had the datepicker loaded in the header of the containing page but have tgried loading it within the script which calls the div content but again no luck. The Jquery library is called in the header of the main page. If I load the pages without ajax then there is no problem and the datepicker works fine.

```
<li><a data-target="#halloffame" href="abscencerecords.php">Absence Records</a></li>
<li><a data-target="#halloffame" href="abscencerequestform.php">Absence Request</a></li>
<li><a data-target="#halloffame" href="personaldetails.php">Personal Details</a></li>
        <?php endif ?>
        <?php endif ?>
        </ul></div>
        <div class="clear padding20"></div>
<div id="halloffame" class="bordered_box"></div>
        <script>
  $('[data-target]').click( function (e) {
   $(document).ready(function() { $("#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' }); }); 
   $(document).ready(function() { $(".datepickermultiple").multiDatesPicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' }); });
    var target = $($(this).attr('data-target')); 
   target.load($(this).attr('href'));
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent anchor from changing window.location
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Where's your field to map out to `datepicker`?  This code is very confusing.  You need to have an input box with id in this case of datepicker, which I strongly suggest you rename.  I'd actually apply a class name to any input text that needs a datepicker and reference that instead.

Comment: please provide enough code to make the example actually work. Additionally, your JS code does not quite make sense: why is there a `$(document).ready()` call inside a click event listener? after a click manual click the load Event will surely never get fired.

Comment: @StefanDochow it may be redundant but won't hurt anything and load will fire. Any time `$(document).ready()` is called after page load it fires immediately

Comment: good to know, but then: why have it? And why keep it, if you know it is redundant?

Comment: You have to reinitialize the datepicker after the datepicker is loaded. Check this questions out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16772876/datepicker-not-working-on-ajax-loaded-content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most plugins only initialize for elements that exist ... at the time the code is run

In order to initialize a plugin within ajax loaded content you need to do that within the completion callback of ajax.

Try changing :

```
target.load($(this).attr('href'));
```

To

```
target.load($(this).attr('href'), function(){
    // new html now exists , initialize plugins or event handlers or dom manipulation here
    $(this).find(selector).somePlugin()
});
```

Reference [load() docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: Thank you - I am still new to learning javascript and this helps me to understand what is going on and will help me when I try to add other javascripts to the called pages.

Answer (score 0):

In my case datepicker plugin was getting initialize, but the issue was position of datepicker calendar, I solved it by adding below CSS to the page:

```
#ui-datepicker-div {
    position: absolute !important;;
}
```